# Why is the axon framework not able to insert in its own table?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, axon

I just started to use the Axon-Framework and I like it a lot. So I wanted to integrate it in an existing project. But when I try to start my application I get the following errors:

```
Fetch Segments for Processor 'my.package.name' failed: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement. Preparing for retry in 4s

ERROR: null value in column "_identifier_mapper_processor_name" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (my.package.name, 0, null, null, null, 2020-01-21T09:32:28.189Z, null, null).
```

I do understand that an unique constraint is violated but the table is managed by the axon framework. I tested it an new project and looked at the database. And the table `token_entry` did not contain the `_identifier_mapper_processor_name` column. Then I looked at the database of my old project and the table contained the two additional columns: `_identifier_mapper_processor_name`, `_identifier_mapper_segment`.

Why does an table of the axon framework sometimes contain these addional columns and sometimes not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be hibernate. The `ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl` naming strategy (which is used by my project) has a problem with `@IdClass`: [Ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11427).

The axon framework uses `@IdClass` for the `token_entry` table. This leads to the error described above.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `_identifier_mapper_processor_name` nor `_identifier_mapper_segment` occur in any search you'd perform on the Axon Framework [GitHub](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework) page. Thus, not in current framework code nor any commits over the last 10 years of Axon's existence.

Hence, I am very hard pressed to understand how you did end up with both columns to begin with. Would you mind sharing what version of Axon you're using and if you are adding any Axon Framework Extensions to the project too?

As far as resolving the problem, I'd assume something is tagging along when creating the `token_entry` table in your existing project.
Any specifics you are doing in your existing project as far as Axon and/or database modification would be beneficial to deduce where this problem stems from.

Comment: Only axon dependency currently installed is axon-spring-boot-starter:4.2.1.
There are no configurations done to the axon framework and all database queries are done by jpa repositories. There are no self written sql queries. Could the problem be related to Querydsl?

Comment: I found were they are comming from: In `org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa` the TokenEntry is annotated with @IdClass. The TokenEntry.PK class contains `processorName` and `segment`. I'm pretty sure that that's how they end up in this table. The question now is why they get serialized in one project and not in the other?

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl
` this property seems to be the problem. As soon as I add it to an sample axon project, I get the errors described above.

Comment: I see you've tackled the problem yourself @NicolasBreuninger, great job! Don't forget to mark it as the answer too ;-)